# C++, can not copy 2 vectors to vector of pair

Tags: c++, vector, copy, std-pair

There the following data types:

```
struct Item { double a, b; Item (double a_, double b_): a(a_), b(b_){}};
typedef std::pair <double, Item> TPair;
typedef std::vector <TPair> TData;
```

I want to copy 2 vectors into the vector of pairs:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector <double> t1;
    std::vector <Item> t2;

    TData data;

    //Error
    std::transform (t1.begin(), t1.end(), data.begin(), 
            std::bind2nd( std::ptr_fun( std::make_pair <double,Item > ), double() ) );
}
```

But the compiler stops with the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'std::pointer_to_binary_function<_Arg1,_Arg2,_Result,_Result(__fastcall *)(_Arg1,_Arg2)> 
std::ptr_fun(_Result (__fastcall *)(_Arg1,_Arg2))' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
Error   2   error C2784: 'std::pointer_to_binary_function<_Arg1,_Arg2,_Result,_Result(__fastcall *)(_Arg1,_Arg2)> 
std::ptr_fun(_Result (__fastcall *)(_Arg1,_Arg2))' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
```

Where is the problem? Thanks for your help. Compiler MSVS 2010 x86. I prefer a solution without Boost.

**Updated question**
An error has been found by dasblinkenlight, the corrected code:

```
std::transform (t1.begin(), t1.end(), data.begin(), std::bind1st( std::ptr_fun( std::make_pair <double,Item > ), double() ) );
```

But compiler shows the same error...

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? There are simpler ways to do this on recent compilers (namely lambda expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `make_pair<double,Item>` is `Item`, not `double`:

```
std::transform (t1.begin(), t1.end(), data.begin(),
     std::bind2nd( std::ptr_fun( std::make_pair <double,Item > ), Item(0,0) ) );
```

EDIT: For MS VS, I defined `make_pair` as follows:

```
std::pair<double,Item> make_pair(const double db, const Item it) {
    return std::pair<double,Item>(db, it);
}
```

Then the invocation looks like this:

```
std::transform (t1.begin(), t1.end(), data.begin(),
     std::bind2nd( std::ptr_fun<double,Item,std::pair<double,Item> >( make_pair), Item(0,0) ) );
```

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Well, in order to use `bind1st` he'd need to replace `t1` with `t2`. I am not quite sure why the OP would like to use transform, because it's hard to use it to "zip" the two vectors together. I'd go for a `for` loop :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There is also a binary version of `std::transform` which is pretty nice for zipping. I don't get why C++11 didn't add an n-ary form though. Sounds like an idea for a proposal to me.

Comment: @justik That is strange, because I lifted that fragment from a program that I just compiled with g++. Here it is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3U3d1xbZ).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: This code under VS2010 does not work, still the same error :-(. The syntax highliting has problem with std::ptr_fun... In another code a construction including std::ptr_fun works well...

Comment: @justik I see what you mean (just copied the code into VS, it does not compile). The problem appears to be that `make_pair` takes a reference for its second parameter, and MS compiler seems to have an issue with that. See my update.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  Thank you very much for your explanation and help... But there is another problem: Adding 2 elements t1.push_back(1); t1.push_back(2); and applying your code results in assertion>: Assertion fail - vector iterator + offset out of range.

Comment: @justik This is because `std::transform` expects the output container to have enough space to fit the transformed range. You need to call `data.resize(t1.size())` to make sure of that. Calling `resize`, in turn, requires a default constructor of `Item`, which you can make by supplying defaults to `a_` and `b_`, like this: `Item (double a_=0, double b_=0): a(a_), b(b_){}`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OK, Thanks for your patience and willingness. It really helps.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `std::make_pair<double,Item>` is an `Item` not a `double`. I guess you want to use `std::bind1st` instead.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes: Yes, you are right... I did not notice it.But there is the same error in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the deprecated binders as they are only going to
take you a few meters before you bump into something that is basically
impossible to solve (member function with more than one argument, more
than 2 arguments, unknown return types) and they are incompatible with
C++11 lambdas. For some degree of forward compatability use
`boost::bind`. Your code effectively becomes:

```
boost::bind(make_pair<double, Item>, double(), _1);
```

Qualifying `make_pair` with template arguments will also be necessary
with `std::bind1st` (`bind1st` because you are binding the argument to
the wrong position, as others have pointed out`).

As an added bonus the C++03 solution:

```
std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(std::make_pair<int, Item>), int());
```

Which, curiously, does not compile with C++11 on 4.6.2. I haven't
figured out why yet. But take it as a good example why you shouldn't
use the deprecated binders!

Comment: Is there any solution without Boost?

Comment: @justik Every modern compiler comes with a `TR1` implementation which has a `std::bind`.